# Trouble searching in VIM with file having lots of slashes and dots

Tags: search, vim

I've got a bunch of really big files that contain lines like:

```
convert ./1776/07/04/T915002.tif ./1776/07/04/T915002.png
rm ./1776/07/04/T915002.tif
convert ./1776/07/04/T918012.tif ./1776/07/04/T918012.png
rm ./1776/07/04/T918012.tif
```

What I want to do is search for say /1861/ meaning a line for the year 1861
But vim seems to interpret that 'go to line 1861, which is not at all what I want.

Searching for the ./1861/ fails too. I assume the leading dot tried to match any character. Trying to backslash quote it fails too. Clearly I'm missing a fundamental idea or two.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a backslash to escape the dot or the slash:

```
/\.\/1861\/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`?`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#?) to search backwards. This means you don't need to escape the `/`s.

```
?/1861/
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same. Plus use `\V` to turn off the `'magic'` setting that makes `.` a special character. `?\V./1776/07`

Comment: @Benoit: `?\./1776/07` is one character shorter ;)